# Reversing default z-index for children in an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

So, the **[spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html)** defines that elements are drawn "in tree order" for in-flow, non-positioned elements of similar `block` level or `float` status and identical `z-index`. This, of course, means those declared last in the HTML markup are drawn on top. But what if we want that order to be reversed for *arbitrary* children in a particular container?

For instance, say we have an indefinite number of overlapping `float` `div`s in a parent `div`:

```
__________________________________
|  _________________________      |
|  | samant| allis| rachael |...  |
|  |_______|______|_________|...  |
|_________________________________|
```

That we want instead to look like this:

```
__________________________________
|  _________________________      |
|  | samantha |lison |chael |...  |
|  |__________|______|______|...  |
|_________________________________|
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ek41mobd/1/)**

Is there still no way to achieve this with css alone? If not, what would be the most efficient and safe way to achieve this functionality with javascript for arbitrary child elements?

Questions have been asked previously for similiar functionality, but not specifically for use in a generic sense with an arbitrary number of child elements. See **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345132/reversing-z-index-based-from-page-render-order)** and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870926/how-to-reverse-z-index-on-stacked-divs)**.

Comment: Here's how I'd do it in JavaScript - iterate the descendent element once to find the max z-index value and the min z-index value - then iterate them again and assign `maxValue + minValue - currentValue` to each one.

Comment: Just float right, instead of left and then they're reversed.

Comment: @slime using `float:right` reverses the entire list though, and aligns them to the right side. What if you want them aligned on the left and in the order in which they are declared? That's why an arbitrary solution is needed. Also, my example uses `float`s but the question considers block-style elements as well.

Answer (score 5):

A simple javascript solution is to get all the elements using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll), then [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and set the `z-index` to the element count - current index:

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".container2 .floater");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elems, function(e, i) {
    e.style.zIndex = elems.length - i;
});
```

```css
.container2 {
    border: 3px solid teal;
    padding: 2em;
    display:inline-block
}


.container2 .floater {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: #444;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: -1em;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
    <div class="floater">Item 1</div>
    <div class="floater">Item 2</div>
    <div class="floater">Item 3</div>
    <div class="floater">Item 4</div>
    <div class="floater">Item 5</div>
    <div class="floater">Item 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will work in simple cases like my example. But, why `map` instead of `forEach`? You don't need the returned array. Also, this doesn't check for pre-set 'z-index' values, which could potentially break things.

Comment: yes `forEach` is better, my mistake. In terms of pre-set z-indexes, if this is how you want it to look, why are you randomly setting  z-indexes on items?

Comment: I could think of cases where you may want a particular child that might be somewhere in the middle to be out in front for example. Could do something like this: `var s = window.getComputedStyle(e);
    if(!s.zIndex || s.zIndex === 'auto'){
        e.style.zIndex = elems.length - i;
    }`

Comment: @Rhumborl Maybe we could set a base zIndex for the component somewhere, and then increment that based on the index of the child.

Answer (score 3):

You can reverse the order of the elements in the document tree to make them overlap like you want.

And then reverse their order using CSS, to place them in the right position again.

This can be achieved, for example, using

- [Flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes):

  ```css
  wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse; /* or `column-reverse` */
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  }
  ul.reversed {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  li {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-left: -1em;
    background: #fff;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <ul>
    <li>Samantha</li>
    <li>Allison</li>
    <li>Rachael</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="reversed">
    <li>Rachael</li>
    <li>Allison</li>
    <li>Samantha</li>
  </ul>
  ```
- [Floating elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float):

  ```css
  wrapper {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
  }
  item {
    float: right;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0 0 0 1em;
  }
  li {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-left: -1em;
    background: #fff;
  }
  ul.reversed > li {
    float: right;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <ul>
    <li>Samantha</li>
    <li>Allison</li>
    <li>Rachael</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="reversed">
    <li>Rachael</li>
    <li>Allison</li>
    <li>Samantha</li>
  </ul>
  ```
- [Direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction):

  ```css
  wrapper {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: left;
  }
  item {
    direction: ltr;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 1em;
    text-align: left;
  }
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-left: -1em;
    background: #fff;
  }
  ul.reversed {
    direction: rtl;
  }
  ul.reversed > li {
    direction: ltr;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <ul>
    <li>Samantha</li>
    <li>Allison</li>
    <li>Rachael</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="reversed">
    <li>Rachael</li>
    <li>Allison</li>
    <li>Samantha</li>
  </ul>
  ```

Comment: Nice way to circumvent without using js, but your solutions appear to be limited to those specific element types (list items and floats). Trying to use your flex box solution to reverse standard block element z-index doesn't get the desired behavior. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvsdmo72/). Although I'm not sure why that is the case. I don't have much experience with flex boxes.

Comment: @NanoWizard It works for me ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvsdmo72/1/)). You didn't reverse the order in the html.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't realize that the second `<ul>` tree was reversed in your example, I thought it was all css. I do like that the solution doesn't require javascript, although declaring the html in reverse is somewhat counter-intuitive.

Comment: @NanoWizard Alternatively, JS could be used to reverse the order in the document tree: `for(var i=wrapper.childNodes.length-2; i>=0; --i) wrapper.appendChild(wrapper.childNodes[i]);`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the new flex boxes.
display: inline-flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse;